# Difference between getting resource via getResource() vs direct way

Tags: android, kotlin

I was wondering what is the difference between 3 ways of reaching the resId in Kotlin if there is any. I was trying to find some simple answer but couldn't find any.

Ways:

1) `resources.getString(R.string.ticketDetailsContactFragment_cannot_send_email)`

2) `getString(R.string.ticketDetailsContactFragment_cannot_send_email)`

3) `R.string.ticketDetailsContactFragment_cannot_send_email`

Example:

```
Toast.makeText(context, R.string.example, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: Case 3 is not relevant. It's just that makeText has an overload that accepts an int instead of a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that 
`resources.getString(R.string.ticketDetailsContactFragment_cannot_send_email)`

and

`getString(R.string.ticketDetailsContactFragment_cannot_send_email)`

will return a `String`

instead
`R.string.ticketDetailsContactFragment_cannot_send_email`  return its resId (`int` value)